# does classes extending Fragment needs to be declared in manifest

Tags: android, android-fragments

I am trying to learn Fragment implementation. Now I have two Fragment class and one MainFragmentDemo class. I have only declared the MainFragmentDemo class in the manifest since it extends Activity. But other two classes are extending Fragment. So I didn't declare it in the manifest. But my app is crashing.
My logcat says like that

```
 java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity   ComponentInfo{com.example.practise/com.example.practise.MainFragmentDemoActivity}
Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #8: Error inflating class fragment
Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException: com.example.practise.ListFragmentDemo cannot be cast to    android.app.Fragment
```

Comment: No, you dont have to declare fragments in manifest. You should show us more of your code so we can understand what is going on.

Comment: ListFragmentDemo extends Fragment?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25823715/should-i-declare-the-mainfragmentdemoactivity-in-menifest ...plz see my this post..

Answer (score 0):

No, they don't. Look [documentation](http://developer.android.com/guide/components/fragments.html) on how to work with fragments.